# MySQL view not editble from ms Access

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access

I have created this view in a MySQL DB.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW users_with_meta_view AS
SELECT wp_usermeta.meta_value
    FROM wp_users INNER JOIN wp_usermeta ON wp_users.ID = wp_usermeta.user_id;
    SELECT
        u1.id,
        u1.user_login,
        m1.meta_value AS firstname,
        m2.meta_value AS lastname
    FROM wp_users u1
    INNER JOIN wp_usermeta m1 ON (m1.user_id = u1.id AND m1.meta_key = 'first_name')
    INNER JOIN wp_usermeta m2 ON (m2.user_id = u1.id AND m2.meta_key = 'last_name')
```

With in PHPMyAdmin I am able to edit the fields in the wiew.

I need to use a MS Access as frontend but from MS Access I'm not able to edit the fields I got the following error in MS Access

> "The recordset is not updateble".

How can I overcome this.

Comment: If the view is updatable by say the MySQL studio or say by a update query, then you can update such views from Access. You will need to delete the linked table (view) from Access, and re-link. When you re-link,, you will and should be prompted to selected the primary key of that view. If you skip this step, the view will be read only. So you should get prompted for the PK during the linking process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view you created is not updatable as it is constructed from joined data.
See [Creating MySQL Updatable Views](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/create-sql-updatable-views.aspx) for more insights.

In your case, you can only read from the view, then used the information to update the individual tables used in constructing the view.

Comment: But within phpadmin i can directly edit on dataset from the view